# Link tag dosen't work in Emberjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, model, ember.js

This is model

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
   revision: 12,
   adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});

App.Markets = DS.Model.extend({
    ids: DS.attr("string"),
    name: DS.attr("string"),
    created: DS.attr("string")
});

App.Markets.FIXTURES = [
    {ids:"312", name:"joy", created:"2012/1/1"},
    {ids:"412", name:"adel", created:"2012/1/2"},
    {ids:"512", name:"john", created:"2012/1/3"}
]; 

App.Sources = DS.Model.extend({
   source_channel: DS.attr("string"),
   handle: DS.attr("handle")
});

App.Sources.FIXTURES = [
    {source_channel:"sc1", handle: "hn1"},
    {source_channel:"sc2", handle: "hn2"}
];
```

This is route.

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('markets', {path: '/markets'}, function() {
        this.resource("sources", { path: "/:market_id" });
    });                                                          
});

App.MarketsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return App.Markets.find();
    }
});

App.SourcesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Sources.find();
    }
});
```

This is template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="_sources">
  {{#each sources in content}}
    <span>{{sources.handle}}</span>
    <span>{{sources.sources_channel}}</span>
  {{/each}}

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="markets">
    {{#each markets in content }}
        {{#linkTo 'sources' markets.ids class="test" }}<span>Source</span>{{/linkTo}}
        <span>{{markets.name}}</span>
        <span>{{markets.created}}</span>

    {{/each}}

    <div class="sources">
        {{partial "sources"}}
    </div>
</script>
```

When I go to `/#/markets`, I can see the markets lists. This is correct.

Focus in `{{#linkTo 'sources' markets.ids class="test" }}Source{{/linkTo}}` of markets template.

In here, `markets.ids` doesn't work. 
I'd like to go to `/#/markets/markets_id` when I click the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with passing the object to the `sources` route in `linkTo`,

define `serialize` method in your `App.SourcesRoute`.

The template:

```
{{#linkTo 'sources' markets class="test" }}<span>Source</span>{{/linkTo}}
```

The Route:

```
 App.SourcesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return App.Sources.find();
    },
    serialize: function(model) {
        return { market_id: model.ids };
    }
});
```

Comment: In case I don't use serialize , when I click some link, I go to #/markets/ember331 etc . ember331 is not markets_id.                  In case I use serialize, when I click some link, I go to #/markets/undefined . :(  I'd like to go to #/markets/(markets_id)

Comment: I think this problem might be due to the absence of `ids` property in your `App.Sources` model, but not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `linkTo 'sources' markets` instead. ie:- pass the model in the each loop to the `linkTo.

Note: Regarding your naming conventions. Ember likes models to be singular, and Routes/Controllers plural or singular depending on whether the route points to one or more models.

### Edit: Clarification.

Change the `linkTo` to this,

```
{{#linkTo 'sources' markets class="test" }}<span>Source</span>{{/linkTo}}
```

Comment: So How do I fix the problem?

Comment: when i am using {{#linkTo 'sources' markets class="test" }}<span>Source</span>{{/linkTo}}, how can I get the market_id?

Comment: You also need the serialize method posted by @Hyder

Comment: In case I don't use serialize , when I click some link, I go to #/markets/ember331 etc . ember331 is not markets_id.                  In case I use serialize, when I click some link, I go to #/markets/undefined . :(  I'd like to go to #/markets/(markets_id)